# Why are the first and last scene not the same in Dear John?

Tags: plot-explanation, dear-john

In the beginning of [*Dear John* (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0989757/), John is dying in a war and he tells us a story about his life.

Here are the first lines from John:

> There's something I wanna **tell you**. After I got shot...you wanna know
>   the very first thing that entered my mind before I blacked out

But the movie ends in a different way, I mean he is not in a war.

Then why are the first and last scene not the same in *Dear John*?

Comment: The scene in the beginning is not John talking to us. Its a flash to the future. Where John will be telling his father through a letter he had written what was going through his mind when he got shot. That scene repeats itself further on in the movie and is explained

Comment: @Mennyg You might want to flesh that out into an answer.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson thanks, just need to find the time to rewatch the scenes